# Use @Query annotation not in the JpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the `User` entity in the database and it's JPA entity. I also have the `UserDescription` class which hasn't table in the database. I want to instantiate `UserDescription` class using different tables and entities. But I don't want to use EntityManager for it. So I found `SELECT new ...` pattern which can be used in `@Query` annotation, it's the perfect solution.

But I have simple issue - I need to annotate some method declaration which should be in interface. Usually it's done in `JpaRepository`, but `UserDescription` - isn't entity, so I can't do this!

Also, I tried to create POJO interface(`UserDescriptionService`) with method declaration which annotated using `@Query` annotation, tried to create field with this interface in the controller(), and annotated it with `Autowired` and of course got:

> Field userDescriptionService in UserController required a bean of type
>   'UserDescriptionService' that could not be found.

So, how can I use `@Query` annotation not in the `JpaRepository` or how can I get `JpaRepository` for the non-entity class?

Comment: You can just put that query on a method in the `UserRepository` and return a `List<UserDescription>` there is no issue with that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Please don't post answers in comments. I'm tired of looking at already answered questions.

Comment: @M.Deinum wow, super easy solution, didn't even think to check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M. Deinum already mentioned. You are not forced to return only Entities in JpaRepositories.

You can use the Constructor Expression (aka select new) or also projections.
Find more about projections here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections